# Why does jQuery, outputs same rel each time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so basically here is my script:

http://jsfiddle.net/JJFap/42/

Code -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var rel = new Array();
    var count = 0;
    jQuery(".setting").each(function() {
        rel[count] = [];
        if(jQuery("span").attr("rel")) {
            rel[count].push(jQuery("span").attr("rel"));
        }  
        console.log(count);
        count++;
    });               
    jQuery("body").text(rel);
    console.log(rel);
});​
```

and

```
<div class="setting">
    <span rel="Variable">Variable</span>
    <span rel="Item">Item</span>
    <span rel="Something">Something</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span rel="Smth">Smth</span>
    <span>Sec</span>
</div>
<div class="setting">
    <span>Second</span>
    <span rel="first">First</span>
    <span rel="Third">Third</span>
</div>
```

​my question, is why does it display Variable, variable?

I would like it to display Variable, First, but I'm not able to do.

Basically what I would like to achieve is create new array, in which insert each div.setting span elements with rel attribute array.

So basically in this example it should output -

```
Array (

   Array[0] => "Variable","Item","Something";

   Array[1] => "first","Third";

)
```

Hope you understood what I meant :)

**EDIT:**

In my other example I tried to add jQuery("span").each(function() ... inside first each function, but it outputted two full arrays of all span elements with rel. I can't have different classes / ids for each div element, since all will have same class.

Comment: Any reason `rel` is an array of arrays, each of which has just one item?

Comment: I think the key to your issue is the jQuery `.find()` function. That lets you find elements starting from a particular point in the DOM tree.

Comment: I wish all SO questions were prepared as well as this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what has been said, you can also get rid of the `count` and one `push()` when using `jQuery.fn.map()` as well as getting rid of the `if` when adding `[rel]` to the selector:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var rel = [];
    jQuery(".setting").each(function() {
        rel.push(jQuery(this).find('span[rel]').map(function() {
            return this.getAttribute('rel');
        }).get());
    });               
    jQuery("body").text(rel);
    console.log(rel);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

`jQuery('span')` is going to find **ALL** spans in your page, and then pull out the `rel` attribute of the first one. Since you don't provide a context for that span search, you'll always get the same #1 span in the document.

Comment: Should I add jQuery(this).children("span") ? Would that fix the problem?

Answer (score 4):

You should be using this:

```
    jQuery('span',this).each(function() {
        rel[count] = [];
        if (jQuery(this).attr("rel")) {
            rel[count].push(jQuery(this).attr("rel"));
        }
        console.log(count);
        count++;
    })
```

instead of this:

```
    rel[count] = [];
    if(jQuery("span").attr("rel")) {
        rel[count].push(jQuery("span").attr("rel"));
    }  
    console.log(count);
    count++;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/JJFap/52/

The trick is to use a second `.each` to loop over all the `span` tags inside each `<div class="setting">` -- your original code was using `jQuery("span")`, which would just grab the first `span` tag in the document every time.

Comment: I think this answer would be greatly improved if you explained **why** they should be using one approach over the other, or why the original approach is incorrect.

Comment: Couldn't you just get rid of the if statement by doing `$.each($(this).find('span[rel]')` ?, also, why not show him how to protect a jQuery function so he doesn't have to write the god-awful 6 character long syntax of 'jQuery` each time!

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I assumed he was using `jQuery` for a good reason. There are probably any number of ways to further optimize this code, but for the purpose of helping the OP learn I keep my changes to his code to a minimum.

Comment: @Blazemonger I think that for the purpose of your code, you should have shown him how to do `(function($){ //$ variable sanitized and safe })(jQuery);`. It's good to pass along knowledge. Regardless, I upvoted anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Within the `.each()` method, you have this code a couple times: `jQuery("span").attr("rel")`. That code simply looks for *ALL* `span` tags on the page. When you stick it inside the `.push()` method, it's just going to push the value for the `rel` attribute of the first jQuery object in the collection. Instead, you want to do something like `$(this).find('span')`. This will cause it to look for any `span` tags that are descendants of the current `.setting` element that the `.each()` method is iterating over.